# How to import json array into java program using JSON.ORG

Tags: java, json

I am learning to work with json files and I'm using the `JSON-java` library from https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

1. I was able to manipulate data for this json dataset

```
{
  "timezone": "UTC",
  "serverTime": 1602321831628,
  "rateLimits": [
    {
      "rateLimitType": "REQUEST_WEIGHT",
      "interval": "MINUTE",
      "intervalNum": 1,
      "limit": 1200
    }
  ],
  "symbols": [
    {
      "symbol": "ETHBTC",
      "status": "TRADING"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using this code

```
JSONTokener jsonToken = new JSONTokener(new FileReader(fileName));
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonToken);
    
//extract all base asset array
JSONArray symbols = jsonObject.getJSONArray("symbols");
```

2. Now I want to manipulate a dataset like this from a .json file

```
[
  {
    "symbol": "ETHBTC",
    "priceChange": "-0.00029700"
  },
  {
    "symbol": "LTCBTC",
    "priceChange": "-0.00003300"
  }
]
```

How do I import this data into my program as an array? I have looked for 8 hours, but could not find a solution. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know this library, but most likely you would use a `JSONArray` instead of a `JSONObject` as the top level element.

Comment: `Array` of what? You are already getting your `symbols.get(0)`. The documentation is provided over here http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html

Comment: @thanks for comment, there are 2 different data json file. the dataset for item ( 1  ) I could import to the program, 
I have issue with the  ( 2 ) dataset  where it doesn't have similar set up as the previous file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, all you have to do is to new a JSON array from `jsonToken` as follows:

BTW, I think the JSON library you are using is `org.json`, not `JSON.ORG`. And both of your JSON strings are invalid, if no other JSON object exists behind comma, please remove it.

**Code snippet**

```java
JSONTokener jsonToken = new JSONTokener(new FileReader(fileName));
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonToken);
System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
System.out.println(jsonArray.get(0));
```

**Console output**

```
[{"priceChange":"-0.00029700","symbol":"ETHBTC"},{"priceChange":"-0.00003300","symbol":"LTCBTC"}]
{"priceChange":"-0.00029700","symbol":"ETHBTC"}
```